# Behavior of costructors in sub classes in Java

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

let's say I have the following code:

```
class A {
  Greating g = new Greating();
  public A(){system.out.print("Creating class A");}
}

class B extends A{
  public B(){system.out.print("Creating class B");}
}

class Greating{
  public Greating(){system.out.print("Hi");}
}
```

What are the outputs when I try to execute

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new B();
}
```

I thought it would first call the constructor of  B and the constructor of B will call the constructor of A but the I don't know which between "creating A" or "Hi" message will be shown first. The first thing invoked on a class should be its constructor but when I executed the program I noticed "Hi" was shown after "Creating A". Why?

Comment: are you sure? the output should be `Hi...A...B` (not `A...Hi...B`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output will be something like bellow:

```
Hi
Creating class A
Creating class B
```

Because at first constructor **Greating()** will be called to initialize property g of A then executed constructor **A()** and then executed constructor **B()**

Comment: Does it mean that a constructor will first check if it has to instantiate any object or variables before starting executing it's code ? So if I had `Greating g = new Greating()` , `Car myCar`, `int numberOfMyBikes = 5`, the constructor will first initialize/instantiate objects and variables? Even if `myCar` has not be instantiated ? And after doing that the constructor will start executing its code showing "Hi" message?

Comment: Yes , for your case ``myCar`` will be initialized by ``null``. And later you can set a value for ``myCar`` inside constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass always calls the constructor of it's superclass at the very beginning of the constructor. Because the constructor of A doesn't have any arguments, you don't need to call it explicitly, but the compiler basically adds super() at the very beginning of B's constructor.

Comment: I guess you mean that it adds super() not A()

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was lost in C++ for a moment there :)